# Antlr 4 c# target doesn't work

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I have Visual Studio 2012 Professional with antlr plugin and when I installed Antlr4 from NuGet and createed new grammar file, it just created empty parser and lexer classes. I tried many ways without success.

Comment: You should post in the support forms for Antlr.

Comment: Just some note, when you install ANTLR runtime with NuGet, do choose the one with right version. I found `ANTLR 4 Runtime` and `ANTLR 4 Standard Runtime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files created by the grammar templates are partial classes where you can include additional code your grammar actions may reference. The actual generated Co is placed in the obj/ folder during the build, and will not appear as files in Solution Explorer (by design, just like Microsoft does with code generated from .xaml files).